# Find the name of the employees, whose names are same but salary are different

Tags: sql

I have an 'employee' table with

```
create table employee
(
  e_number int,
  e_name varchar(20),
  salary money,
  hire_date date
)
```

Now I want to display only the name of the employees who have the same name but different salary.

I tried `select e_name,count(*) from employee  group by e_name having count(*)>1;`
but cannot combine it with "the same salary" section. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that you want the names of both of the people listed:

```
SELECT e1.e_name
FROM employee e1, employee e2
WHERE e1.e_name = e2.e_name
AND e1.salary <> e2.salary;
```

If you only want each name listed once, you would use a SELECT DISTINCT instead of the SELECT.

Comment: I get the same name printed four times.

Comment: What if you use SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the use of <> operator?

Comment: <> is simply the syntax for 'not equals'.  Think of it as having to be both greater than and less than, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to express this in the having clause:

```
Select name 
 from employee
 group by name
 having 
   count(*) > 1
   and min(salary) != max(salary)
 order by name
```

Comment: just coming from a MS SQL background, wouldn't you want `min(salary) <> max(salary)` instead of `!=`?

Comment: @Greg Is that the case in MS Sql?  != is my Oracle background... whatever 'not equal' operator works in the target DBMS.  I kind of like the confusion this would cause min(salary) < max(salary).

Comment: Works fine but can u please describe the working of min(salary) != max(salary)?

Comment: The Having clause is a where clause that is applied AFTER aggregation.  So we are asking is the minimum salary within that aggregation different than max salary?  If yes, allow the aggregation to be included in the returned rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee1.e_name, employee1.Salary, Employee2.Salary
FROM Employee employee1
JOIN Employee employee2
  on employee1.name = employee2.name
 AND Employee1.Salary <> Employee2.Salary
 AND Employee1.E_Number <> employee2.E_Number
```

Basically get every employee, join it to every other employee via name, where the employee number is different (so don't join to yourself) and salary is different.

You probably don't need to check that employee number is different because 1 employee can only have 1 salary in your table design

Answer (score 0):

Use a join, but importantly use a greater-than comparison, rather than a not-equals, to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT e1.e_name as name1, e2.e_name as name2
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2 ON e1.e_name = e2.e_name
    AND e1.salary > e2.salary;
```

Note also that the ON condition contains the salary comparison. It is a common misconception that the join on condition may only contain key-related comparisons. Doing this can have significant performance benefits, especially when further joins are made, because the ON condition is executed as the rows are joined - which discards non-matches immediately, whereas WHERE conditions are executed as a filter on the entire result set of the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You just want the count of distinct salaries, not the count of all records.

```
select e_name,count(distinct salary)
from employee
group by e_name
having count(distinct salary)>1
```

(Drop the count in the select if unneeded - included since it was in your example)

Answer (score 0):

First filter salary not double (not in), then grouping by `e_name` having count > 1

```
SELECT A.e_name
FROM employee A 
WHERE A.salary NOT IN (SELECT salary FROM employee  WHERE id != A.id)
GROUP BY A.e_name
HAVING COUNT(A.e_name) > 1
```